# F11 does NOT debug stepinto --> using somePkg

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia

```
My code has (bp=breakpoint)
    #tutee-01
bp  z=1
bp  using somePkg
bp  z=2
```

After debug arrives at the   'using'   line,
when I press F11 noting happens immediately
and after a while it highlightes the next line   z=2

I expect F11 on the  'using'  should take me to the
place where the parsing of my source happens,
and show me what occurs in response to the  using.

grep for  'function using'  in the julia package code in
C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Programs/Julia-1.9.3/share/julia/
does not find any hits.

I am using  VSCode  Version: 1.85.1 (system setup)
Node.js: 18.15.0   V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 Win10.0.19045
tkx, Paul